# Mime-Type to PDF and Print ist

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, mime

I have in a XML-Data a Mime-Type PDF Data and I want to print that data. I'm using C# as programming language. I have no idea how it works and I started with C# 3 Months ago, because of my job.

The PDF-Data is a bill, which should print by packing.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.. do you mean you're looking for the mime-type of pdf? If so then it's `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";`

Comment: I have a mime converted pdf data in a xml tag. And i want to print that pdf.